# Convert json data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, json

I want to modify JSON data in React js
I have a sample JSON file

```
[
 {
 "id": 1,
"name": "A",
"day": "mon",
"candidate": 5
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "A",
"day": "mon",
"candidate": 4
 },
 {
"id": 3,
"name": "A",
"day": "mon",
"candidate": 3
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "A",
"day": "tue",
"candidate": 2
}
]
```

I want to change like this format bellow

```
 const data = {
   Monday: [
       {day: "mon", name: 'A', candidate: '5'},
      {day: "mon", name: 'A', candidate: '4'},
       {day: "mon", name: 'A', candidate: '3'}
   ],
   tuesday: [
    {day: "tue", name: 'B', candidate: '1'},
   ]
 }
```

Please help me to change to this format :(

**Edit**
I try to make JSON data to what data I want, but the final result temp is only tue not mon ?

```
useEffect(() => {
let temp = {};
dataJson.forEach(item => {
    if(item.day === 'mon'){
        const newArr = {moday: item}
        temp = newArr;
    }
    if(item.day === 'tue'){
        const newArr = {tue: item}
        temp = newArr;
    }
});
console.log("tempt", temp)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example :
you can put in a loop if you want

```
const data = 
[
  {
     "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 5
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 4
     },
     {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 3
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "tue",
    "candidate": 2
    }
 ]

console.log(data.filter(item => item.day === 'mon'))
```

Comment: I post my solution, could you help me take a look? might I not get what data i want as begin

Answer (score 0):

it can help you

```
  const data = [
     {
     "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 5
    },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 4
     },
     {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "mon",
    "candidate": 3
    },
    {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "A",
    "day": "tue",
    "candidate": 2
    }
    ]
    let newNewData = []
    data.map(item => {
        return newNewData.push({[item.day]: item})
    })
    console.log(newNewData)
```